# How to cancel delete using AbstractMongoEventListener?

Tags: spring-mongodb

Can I cancel delete event using `onBeforeDelete` method of `MongoGenreCancelDeleteEventsListener`? If yes then how?

```
@Component
public class MongoGenreCancelDeleteEventsListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Genre> {
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    @Override
    public void onBeforeDelete(BeforeDeleteEvent<Genre> event) {
        super.onBeforeDelete(event);
       // check conditions and cancel delete
    } 
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue and I found a solution.

Basically, your code should become like this:

```java
@Component
public class MongoGenreCancelDeleteEventsListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Genre> {

    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Override
    public void onBeforeDelete(BeforeDeleteEvent<Genre> event) {
        super.onBeforeDelete(event);
        boolean abort = false;
        //do your check and set abort to true if necessary
        if (abort) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(); //or any exception you like
        }
    } 

}
```

The thrown exception prevents the operation from going further and it stops there. Also, the exception gets propagated to the caller (anyway, it is wrapped inside a `UndeclaredThrowableException`, so this is what you should catch; make sure that the wrapped exception is indeed the one you've thrown by calling the `getCause()` method).

Hope it helps.